# How to receive JSON data on WebAPI backend C#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

How do I receive JSON data on my WebAPI backend in C#?

I have the following JSON sent from my JavaScript frontend.

```
{
    "User_Id": 1,
    "TotalPrice": 35,
    "DeliveryAddress": "At my house",
    "CartItems": [
        {
            "Id": 1009,
            "Name": "Superman juni 2014",
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Price": 35
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this classes:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
    {        
        public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
        public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public int User_Id { get; set; }
    }
public class CartItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

And my WebAPI method:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public bool AddOrder(PurchaseOrder order)
        {
            // Here I will do something

            return true;
        }
```

I only get "null" as the result for my "PurchaseOrder order" object. Can the problem be that I´m using [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]? I have also tried [System.Web.Http.HttpPost], but get the same result.
// Martin

Comment: Do you set the Content-Type to `application/json` on the JavaScript request?

Comment: Can you include the full Javascript request?

Comment: build a javascript object named `order` with your data and use `JSON.stringify` while posting.

Comment: Unless you're using vNext, this is wrong `System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost` it should come from the `Http` namespace I believe not the `Mvc` one. Secondly this is something to do with your JavaScript.

Answer (score 20):

The `Content-Type` of your request should be `"application/json"`

If you post your json in a body of the request than change a method signature to

```
[HttpPost]
public bool AddOrder([FromBody] PurchaseOrder order)
{
}
```

Comment: `contentType` in javascript.

Comment: `[FromBody]` might not be necessary.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh No, `[FromBody]` is mostly assuredly necessary.  By default, a WebApiController instance looks in the URL for parameters.  If you're using a JSON string and posting that, instead, it has to look in the request body.

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved, it was the "application/json" that was missing. For other persons having the same problem, here is my function. I´m using Knockout.js, hence the "self"-word.

```
self.makePurchase = function () {
            var tempUserId = self.orderUserId();
            var tempCartPrice = self.ShoppingCartPrice();
            var tempAddress = self.orderAddress();
            var tempCart = self.ShoppingCart();

            var orderSave = new PurchaseSave(tempUserId, tempCartPrice, tempAddress, tempCart);
            var myData = ko.toJSON(orderSave);
            console.log(myData);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: '/Products/AddOrder',
                contentType: "application/json", // Thank you Stackoverflow!!!
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: myData,
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log("Inside the error method");

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Inside the success method");

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: `var self = this` is a common thing, just let's you know what `this` you are referring to as this can change when you are inside say `error: function () {}` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Change your implementation to this.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public bool AddOrder([FromBody] PurchaseOrder order)
{

}
```

For more details - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: for WebApi, you should use this attribute `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]`

Comment: @SaveendraEkanayake Looks like you were typing up this response at the same time as Anton & just submitted it 11 mins after he did...  But it's basically the same thing-at least you have a link.  Missed the part about the Content-Type.. but it didn't help that the OP didn't post his JavaScript - if he had, I'm sure you would've caught that, though.  :wink:

Answer (score -4):

Try using Newtonsoft.Json package from NuGet. They have functions to serialize and deserialize any string to Json.
Also try using dynamic type variables. Helps for deserializing.

Comment: this is not an answar.

Comment: Not an answer either.