# Asp.net WebApi add one item in nested child list when list is set to null in json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have  the following json Object which i am sending to Web Api controller Using ajax.

```
var dataObject = {
                    LanguageId: 1,
                    SubTenantId: 1,
                    Object:{"TestApplication":{"Aplication":null}} 
                }
```

Controller function RequestObject generic class.

```
 public IHttpActionResult ComplexObject(RequestObject<TestApplicationMain> pubRequestObject)
```

I am using following Class hierarchy.

```
public class TestApplicationMain
{
    public TestApplicationMain()
    {
        TestApplication = new TestApplication();
    }
 public TestApplication TestApplication{get; set;}

}

public class TestApplication
{
    public TestApplication()
    {
        Aplication = new List<ApplicationSearchParam>();
    }
    public List<ApplicationSearchParam> Aplication { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationSearchParam
{
    public ApplicationSearch ApplicationSearch { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

When i send `{"TestApplication":{"Aplication":null}}` json to the controller. I receive One item `Aplication` .

Api controller works as expected when i send    `{"TestApplication":{"Aplication":undefined}}` OR  `{"TestApplication":{"Aplication":[]}}`

**My Question is Why Asp.net WebApi Controller add one item in nested child list when its set to null ?**.

Comment: What is the item inside `Aplication` ? When I test your code, what I've seen for `Aplication` is `List<ApplicationSerachParam>` with 0 count. And this is normal beacuse, you are instantiating in constructor.

Comment: Include `RequestObject<T>` in the [mcve]

Comment: ApplicationSerachParam is a class having a number of. with Appliacation:null i receive one List<ApplicationSerachParam> with 1 count

Comment: i think you missing something in your code can you post the rest of the controller and models?

Comment: I would suggest you work with the Framework as you have evaluated.  In my experience, always pass a value (non-NULL) to Web API, so that it will properly map to properties.  Also, best to accept a JSON object into your Web API and try not to Auto-Map the JSON to .Net Object.  You are adding many layers of obscurity that will be hard to track-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Problem Spotted:

```
var dataObject = {
                    LanguageId: 1,
                    SubTenantId: 1,
                    Object:{"TestApplication":{"Aplication":null}} 
                }
```

1. Your JSON is at a level higher than `TestApplicationMain`
2. You defined `LanguageId` and `SubTenantId` but your receiving class `TestApplicationMain` does not handle either of the values.
3. You have not defined `Object` in `TestApplicationMain`

The reason your first test scenario `{"TestApplication":{"Aplication":null}}` works is because `TestApplication` is a property of `TestApplicationmain`

When you are automapping JSon Key-Value pairs, the name of the Key needs to match the name of the Property you wish its value to be assigned.

You test JSON should be:

```
var dataObject = {"TestApplication":{"Aplication":""}}
```

as this structure would map to:

```
TestApplicationMain -> TestApplication -> Aplication = ""
```

My Suggestions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31022729/659246
- https://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/

Comment: I new this work with [] undefined and "" but  i want to make work with null

Comment: then wrap NULL in text `"null"` or handle the NULL value in Web API...be prepared for unhandle situations when relying on automapping.  I accept JSON as a string and parse using JsonSerializer object and manually map the fields I am expecting to the class/properties.